# How to check programatically if url of page is redirecting?

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to extract the content of a webpage A. Using groovy I've tried the following

```
......
String urlStr = "url-of-webpage-A"
String pageText = urlStr.toURL().text
//println pageText
.....
```

The above code retrieves the text of webPage A as long as it doesn't redirect to an other webpage B. If A redirects to B, the page content of webPage B is retrieved in the pageText variable. Is there a way to code and check if webPage A is redirecting to an other webpage (in groovy or java)?

PS: The above piece of code is not a part of server side logic. I am executing it on the client side within the scope of a desktop appilcation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In groovy, you could do what [Joachim suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413801/how-to-check-programatically-if-url-of-page-is-redirecting/7413864#7413864) by doing:

```
String location = "url-of-webpage-A"
boolean wasRedirected = false
String pageContent = null

while( location ) {
  new URL( location ).openConnection().with { con ->
    // We'll do redirects ourselves
    con.instanceFollowRedirects = false

    // Get the response code, and the location to jump to (in case of a redirect)
    location = con.getHeaderField( "Location" )
    if( !wasRedirected && location ) {
      wasRedirected = true
    }

    // Read the HTML and close the inputstream
    pageContent = con.inputStream.withReader { it.text }
  }
}

println "wasRedirected:$wasRedirected contentLength:${pageContent.length()}"
```

If you don't want to be redirected, and want the contents of the first page, you simply need to do:

```
String location = "url-of-webpage-A"
String pageContent = new URL( location ).openConnection().with { con ->
  // We'll do redirects ourselves
  con.instanceFollowRedirects = false

  // Get the location to jump to (in case of a redirect)
  location = con.getHeaderField( "Location" )

  // Read the HTML and close the inputstream
  con.inputStream.withReader { it.text }
}

if( location ) { 
  println "Page wanted to redirect to $location"
}
println "Content was:"
println pageContent
```

Comment: Hi Tim, I tried the above code but it is still retrieving the content of the new Location/Redirected webpage. :( I need the content of the original page.

Comment: @VeeKay Oh...  I thought you wanted the content of the final page, but to know you were redirected... I've added a different method to do what I hope you wanted...

Answer (score 14):

In Java you can use `URL.openConnection()` to get a [`HttpURLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) (you'll need to cast). On this you can call [`setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setInstanceFollowRedirects%28boolean%29).

Then you can use [`getResponseCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode%28%29) and see if [`HTTP_MOVED_PERM`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#HTTP_MOVED_PERM) (301), [`HTTP_MOVED_TEMP`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#HTTP_MOVED_TEMP) (302) or [`HTTP_SEE_OTHER`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#HTTP_SEE_OTHER) (303). They all indicate redirection.

If you need to know *where* you're being redirected to, then you can use [`getHeaderField("Location")`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#getHeaderField%28java.lang.String%29) to get the location header.