# How to find URL of page returned from XmlSlurper.parse(aURL) after redirect in Groovy

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

How do I in Groovy get the URL of a page returned from XmlSlurper.parse(aURL) after redirect. Wild guessed and tried  parser.getProperty("document.location") without luck.

Comment: You mean you parse a URL, that URL is redirected, and you want to know the URL of the page you actually parsed?

Comment: If so, you can [do something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7414109/6509) to follow redirects until you get to a final URL, then just parse that URL with `XmlSlurper`

Comment: That may be the best solution. I was hoping for something more direct, since when viewing the GPathResult structure in IntelliJ, I see the string "document.location = 'http://etc...';" in the variable content of the gpathresult.